# How to declare a template function that takes an output_iterator of T?

Tags: c++, c++-concepts

I want to put objects into a container (which container is not fixed).

For that I want to use the concept `std::output_iterator`.

How would I define a function that takes for example a `std::insert_iterator<std::vector<T>>` and a `std::insert_iterator<std::list<T>>`?

the concept `std::output_iterator` takes two template arguments : `I` and `T`. So i am unsure how I would declare such a function.

I could do it like oldschool `<algorithm>` and declare it like this:

```cpp
template<typename OutIter>
void foo(OutIter writer);
```

but thats not that expressive imo.

---

**UPDATE:** Here is my attempt based in [@RemyLebeau's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75896018/65863):

```cpp
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
template<typename I, typename T, std::output_iterator<I,T> OutIter>
void foo(OutIter writer) {
    writer++ = T();
}

int main() {

    std::vector<int> ints;
    auto inserter = std::insert_iterator(ints,ints.end());
    foo(inserter);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/afe9rz3c4

Comment: what does not make sense? I want a function that accepts a `input_iterator<vector<T>>`, `input_iterator<list<T>>`. both are `output_iterator`. I just have no idea how to declare it.

Comment: those are examples... just like written in my Question.

Comment: huh? `std::output_iterator` is a CONCEPT. I want to write a template function that restricts the function to accepting output iterators. I just have no idea how to declare it with the concept.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@Remy Lebeau has the right idea, but not the right execution. The first template argument to a concept is the type being constrained and does not have to be specified when used to restrain another template arg.

Their answer with correct code:

```cpp
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

template<typename T, std::output_iterator<T> OutIter> // note: no template argument I required
void foo(OutIter writer) {
    writer++ = T();
}

int main() {

    std::vector<int> ints;
    auto inserter = std::insert_iterator(ints,ints.end());
    foo<int>(inserter); // note you have to specify int when calling foo
    return 0;
}
```

This is not entirely your use-case, since you don't want to specify the type for foo's iterator when calling the function. But using the output_iterator concept, foo can specify the iterator type itself:

```cpp
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

template<std::output_iterator<int> OutIter> // Explicitly requests an iterator that ints can be written to
void foo(OutIter writer) {
    writer++ = int{};
}

int main() {

    std::vector<int> ints;
    auto inserter = std::insert_iterator(ints,ints.end());
    foo(inserter);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i did not know you can specify the type in a nested template. Thank you very much!